# Что такое грамотность?

Tags: орфография, общие-вопросы, фонетика

Понятно, что если человек не умеет ни читать, ни писать, то назвать грамотным его вряд ли возможно. Хотя при желании можно вспомнить людей, которые читать или писать не могут из-за физических недугов, но тем не менее надиктовывали книги, которыми зачитывались во всём мире. Они тоже неграмотные? 
А те кто пишут, но допускают по 5 ошибок в слове из 4 букв грамотные?

А если нет, то чем отличается грамотный человек от неграмотного?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Не умеет" и "не может из-за физических недугов" - большая разница. Если он создаёт грамотно построенный текст - он уже грамотный, знаком с грамматикой - морфологией и синтаксисом. Если будут допущены ошибки при его записи - это не его ошибки, а того, кто писал. Грамотный человек владеет нормами устной и письменной речи - орфоэпии, словообразования, лексики, морфологии,орфографии, синтаксиса и пунктуации. Устная речь тоже  выдаёт  неграмотного человека - он нарушает речевые нормы.

Comment: А что такое "владеет нормами"? "Мы все учились понемногу...", и пару фраз сказать-написать может каждый носитель языка. И если брать словарную норму, то каждый носитель языка будет допускать осознанные или бессознательные ошибки как в письменной, так и в устной речи. Где находится та граница, когда этот грамотен, а этот  уже нет?

P.S. При написании текста выше, браузер исправил 4 ошибки (опечатки и удвоенная -н-), скорей всего, их я бы и сам обнаружил при перечитывании, но мог бы и пропустить. Могу ли я после этого считать себя грамотным человеком?

Comment: Ну, это уже сами оценивайте себя. Как в школе, там всё просто: 50% работы с ошибками - "2",нормы оценок знаете, вот и смотрите, насколько грамотны. Если на "2" - неграмотный, если на "3" - посредственные знания, на "4" - хорошие, на "5" - отличные. Грамотный тот, кто редко делает ошибки. Абсолютно грамотных людей, наверно, нет или единицы. А просто грамотных на моём пути было много.

Comment: Так это и интересно. "Создать грамотно построенный текст" любого уровня сложности, для меня не проблема, но если буду его записывать сам, то ошибок будет чуть больше, чем необходимо по норме на школьную "3".

Как показывают результаты тотальных диктантов, даже люди интересующиеся русским языком (а иначе зачем тратить время на диктант?), пишут в подавляющем большинстве на "2". Вот и интересно из-за чего из "орфоэпии, словообразования, лексики, морфологии,орфографии, синтаксиса и пунктуации" выделяют только орфографию с пунктуацией и считают их основным мерилом грамотности?

Comment: Потому что орфографическая и пунктуационная грамотность на поверхности, её видно сразу, а вот качества речи сразу видны в устном разговоре, а письменную речь мы используем мало и почти не развиваем, если только не работаем там, где нужно создавать тексты. Я считаю, если для Вас не проблема создать текст,орфографическая неграмотность вызвана школьными пробелами, нужно их восполнить, заняться этим серьёзно, способов много, один из них - переписывание текстов классиков, Толстого, например, выработается "моторный инстинкт".

Answer (score 2):

"Грамотный" -  слово многозначное.
 1. Умеющий читать и писать. 2. Умеющий грамматически правильно писать. 3.Написанный без ошибок (Грамотное письмо). 4. перен. Умелый, осведомленный в чем-н.5. Выполненный с известным мастерством и знанием дела (Вполне грамотная работа. Рисунок грамотен). Может иметь ироническое значение (Уж больно ты грамотный)